# Angularjs ngresources cannot get the url

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngresource

i have the following url "http://localhost:3000/api/user/" 
and is work fine in the browser,
but when i put it in my ionic service code 
`return $resource('/api/user/');` 
is return

> data : cannot Get /api/user\n

and when i change the url to url from some api in the web is work fine and get the data right .. please what the wrong here.

Comment: This might sound silly but if you have copied it from some pdf it might be using some weird ascii characters happened to me once. Just re-type it by hand.

Comment: that's really silly, but i didn't copy it and i retype the code and the same problem

Comment: Would guess its more to do with your server than the client side code. Get rid of the trailing slash and add the headers for content type etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is link to the port :3000. When you write /api/user/, angular go to search your url on http://localhost/api/user/ and not http://localhost:3000/api/user/.

So to resolved this issue you have to pass all your url to the $ressource() and not only the last part.

Comment: now it return > {data :null,status:-1,config:{methode:get,transformRequest:[null],transformResponse:[null],url:"http://localhost:3000/api/user",header:{accept:application/json,text/plain,*/*}},"statusText:""}   ,but in my browser the url bring JOSN array !!.

Comment: Can you show me more code ? Because $resource return only an angular object to fetch data you have to use $ressource(url).query() for example.